# Rails is routing to Page not found instead of 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently created an `errors_controller.rb` file which basically will route all non-existing page even those unathorized page by non-admin users to a 404 page:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def page_not_found
      show_404
    end
  end
```

And then on my `routes.rb` file:

```
match '*path', via: :all, to: 'errors#page_not_found'
```

I am using [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) gem for my authorization and here's my users policy:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    class Scope < Scope
      def resolve
        scope.all
      end
    end

    def index?
      user.admin? 
    end 
  end
```

Now the problem is whenever I visits a page that is non existing it shows me this:

[image]

But if a non-admin user visit a page that is unathorized to access (for instance localhost:3000/users-list), it's showing this:

[image]

How do I make sure to show the 404 page or a specific page on my public folder whenever an unathorized user visits a page that is can only access by an admin?
UPDATE: Here's the content of my `application_controller.rb` file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Pundit
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show_404

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       stored_location_for(resource) || contacts_path
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end

     protected

          def configure_permitted_parameters
               devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:user_avatar, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}

               devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:user_avatar, :name, :email, :password, :current_password)}
          end

    private

    def user_not_authorized
      flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
      redirect_to action: :index
    end 

    def show_404
      render template: "errors/404", status: 404
    end 
end
```

Comment: i guess you have some statement like `rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized`, can you add more about the action will be called when Pundit::NotAuthorizedError raised

Comment: `rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized` I got this on my application controller.

Comment: I just updated the question above.

Comment: Yup, the picture(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFQjU.png) tell that: you have redirect too many time. It seem like when your request /users-list, some action will redirect you to other path, but you still unauthorize too, it will redirect to other path again and go on....

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite `user_not_authorized` on controller, that you call when a non-admin user visit a page that is unathorized to access

```
def user_not_authorized
  show_404
end
```